# remove spacing that surrounds a command in general

Tags: spacing

[image]Say you have a document that is strictly double-spaced. But when you use commands such as `\defn` or `\footnote`, it's looks like 3 spaces before and after a definition. How do you remove such extra added lines?

```
\begin{defn} 
some text here
\end{defn}

\begin{Properties}
\item a
\item b
\item c
\end{Properties}
```

I tried `\ignorespaces` but that does not work.

Picture corresponds, to:

```
\subsection{Test Subsection}
ahdjashdsajdhasjdhsjadhasjdhsajkdhasjkdhsajkdhasas adasjkdashdksajhdsajkhdjsakdhsad
adhsakjdhsakdhsajkdhasjkhdjsakhdaskdhaskjhdkjas asdhaskjdhsajkdhsajkhdjksahdjaskhdjksadhsajkdhsa
asdhkashdjksahdjksahdjksahdjksahdjksahdkjsahdjkashdjkashdjksha
\begin{defn}a:= a letter\end{defn}
dsasjdkhsakjdhaskjdhsakjdhsadsahdsakjdhajshdjsahdjkashdjksahdkjsahdjksahdjksahjkdhsajkdhasjkdhsajkd
asdaksjdhsajkdhsajkhdjaskhdjsakhdkjsahdjsahjdksahdjsahdjkhsajkdhsajkhdjsakhdjkashdjksahdjkashdjsahdkas
```

using:

```
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{lem}[thm]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{cor}[thm]{Corollary}
\newtheorem{conj}[thm]{Conjecture}
\newtheorem*{main}{Main Theorem}
\theoremstyle{definition}
**\newtheorem{defn}[thm]{Definition}**
\newtheorem{rem}[thm]{Remark}
\newtheorem{exmp}[thm]{Example}
\newtheorem{ques}[thm]{Question}
\usepackage{enumitem}
**\newlist{Properties}{enumerate}{2}
\setlist[Properties]{label=Property \arabic*.,itemindent=*}**
\usepackage{algorithmicx}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{xlop}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Could you add a [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) to show exactly what you mean?

Comment: Hi, Thank you. I will post a picture.  For the case: double spaced text and triple space surrounding something like \begin{defn} 
some text here
\end{defn}. How do you use negative spacing to remove added extra blank lines by some commands.

Comment: @user203615 A picture does not let the readers of the question reproduce the problem. Your snippet of code also doesn't. `\ignorespaces` takes care of horizontal glue due to space-tokens while your problem seems to be related to vertical glue. In oder to find out where that vertical glue comes from and how to adjust that one needs to reproduce the problem.  E.g., the documentclass in use is unknown. Where do environments `defn` and `Properties` come from? Blind guess: underlying list-environment with `\topsep` (and `\partopsep`)-glue before/behind the text of the environment-body...

Comment: \newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{lem}[thm]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{cor}[thm]{Corollary}
\newtheorem{conj}[thm]{Conjecture}
\newtheorem*{main}{Main Theorem}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{defn}[thm]{Definition}
\newtheorem{rem}[thm]{Remark}
\newtheorem{exmp}[thm]{Example}
\newtheorem{ques}[thm]{Question}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newlist{Properties}{enumerate}{2}
\setlist[Properties]{label=Property \arabic*.,itemindent=*}
\usepackage{algorithmicx}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{xlop}

Comment: I got it. \vspace{-7pt}\, \vspace{-16pt}

Comment: You haven't shown us how you're getting double-spacing, so how can we suggest a better way?

Answer (score 0):

Seems the environment `defn` adds vertical glue above and below its text in the same way list-like-environments do:

In case the environment does not form a paragraph on its own, vertical glue is inserted above and below the environment's text according to the value of the register `\topsep`.

In case the environment does form a paragraph on its own, additionally to the `\topsep`-glue vertical glue is inserted above and below the environment's text according to the value of the register `\partopsep`.

You can within a group/local scope set `\topsep` and `\partopsep` to 0pt:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{setspace} 
\doublespacing

\usepackage{amsthm}

\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{lem}[thm]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{cor}[thm]{Corollary}
\newtheorem{conj}[thm]{Conjecture}
\newtheorem*{main}{Main Theorem}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{defn}[thm]{Definition}
\newtheorem{rem}[thm]{Remark}
\newtheorem{exmp}[thm]{Example}
\newtheorem{ques}[thm]{Question}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newlist{Properties}{enumerate}{2}
\setlist[Properties]{label=Property \arabic*.,itemindent=*}
\usepackage{algorithmicx}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{xlop}

\begin{document}
\subsection{Test Subsection}
ahdjashdsajdhasjdhsjadhasjdhsajkdhasjkdhsajkdhasas adasjkdashdksajhdsajkhdjsakdhsad
adhsakjdhsakdhsajkdhasjkhdjsakhdaskdhaskjhdkjas asdhaskjdhsajkdhsajkhdjksahdjaskhdjksadhsajkdhsa
asdhkashdjksahdjksahdjksahdjksahdjksahdkjsahdjkashdjkashdjksha
\begingroup
\topsep=0ex
%\partopsep=0ex
\begin{defn}a:= a letter\end{defn}%
\endgroup
dsasjdkhsakjdhaskjdhsakjdhsadsahdsakjdhajshdjsahdjkashdjksahdkjsahdjksahdjksahjkdhsajkdhasjkdhsajkd
asdaksjdhsajkdhsajkhdjaskhdjsakhdkjsahdjsahjdksahdjsahdjkhsajkdhsajkhdjsakhdjkashdjksahdjkashdjsahdkas
\end{document}
```

The result looks like this:

[image]